# Как добавить "прыжок" в С# скрипт на Unity 3D с помощью Character Controller?

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

Сделал скрипт передвижения персонажа в Unity с плавным поворотом в 8 направления, но не знаю как добавить прыжок в скрипт и ничего не сломать.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float turnSmoothTime;
    
    void Update() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
       
        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f) {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f); 
            controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно както так
private void Jump()
    {
        rigidbody.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

Comment: Извините, но я использую Character Controller и поэтому я не могу воспользоваться командами для rigid body.

Comment: "Unity 3D  Character Controller jump" - все ключевики которые есть в заголовке вопроса дают в гугле ответы как в текстовом виде так и в виде видеоуроков

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по документации самого юнити https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

> (кстате там много всего интересного есть, советую к прочтению)

```
void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection *= speed;

            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

но лучше читать саму документацию, там ответ шире.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        if (_charController.isGrounded)
        {
            movement.y = jumpHeight;

        }
    }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // в частности, объясните, чем принципиально ваш ответ отличается от предыдущего